# merge_asof pandas python (multiple rows)

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas data frames. They rows need to be matched by two values (X,Y) coordinates which are not exact matches but within a tolerance.. I need to add the 'VAL' term from df2 to the 'VAL' term from df1 where (X,Y) match.

I've attempted using merge_asof without luck. I think if I could get the merge_asof to work the way I'm expecting I can do the addition and re-assignment to df2 but so far I'm unable to get the matching to work out.

Here is an example of the code I have attempted.

```
d1 = [ ['wp1',0.0,0.0,10],['wp2',10.0,10.0,5],['wp3',7.0,7.0,5]]
d2 = [ ['wp4',0.1,0.1,5],['wp5',10.2,10.2,8]]
headers = ['Name','X','Y','VAL']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1,columns = headers)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2,columns = headers)


#attempt at solution just to find matching values
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('VAL'), df2.sort_values('VAL'),on=['VAL'],by=['X','Y'],direction='nearest',tolerance=1)


#desired solution is to sum 'VAL' from df2 into df1 
d1_final = [ ['wp1',0.0,0.0,10+5],['wp2',10.0,10.0,5+8]]
df1_final = pd.DataFrame(d1_final,columns = headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated, your matching within tolerance is required on `X,Y`.  With `merge_asof()` the tolerance matching happens with the `on=` parameter.  (the `by=` parameter provides exact matching that happens prior to the `on=` tolerance matching - think `grouby`).  BUT `on=` can only tolerance match on a single key.  So you cannot do `on=['X','Y']` to get you to where you want to go.  `merge_asof` won't work for a tolerance match on multiple keys.

Quick thought.  Wish I had more time right now.  Just tolerance match on `X`. `dropna()`.  Then do a secondary tolerance filtering on the `Y` values.  That info will be part of the merge.  If the `Y`'s are less than the tolerance - then just add the `VAL`s for your final answer.

```
df4 = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values(['X','Y']), df2.sort_values(['X','Y']), on='X', direction='nearest', tolerance=1)  
df4

  Name_x     X   Y_x  VAL_x Name_y   Y_y  VAL_y
0    wp1   0.0   0.0     10    wp4   0.1    5.0
1    wp3   7.0   7.0      5    NaN   NaN    NaN
2    wp2  10.0  10.0      5    wp5  10.2    8.0
```

Then do the process outlined above:

```
df5 = df4.assign(VAL=np.where((df4['Y_x']-df4['Y_y']).abs()<1, df4['VAL_x']+df4['VAL_y'], np.nan) ) \
    .rename(columns={'Name_x':'Name','Y_x':'Y'}).dropna()[['Name','X','Y','VAL']] 
df5

  Name     X     Y   VAL
0  wp1   0.0   0.0  15.0
2  wp2  10.0  10.0  13.0
```

Comment: Hey jch I appreciate you helping out here. I tried to follow this method but I am obtaining a different result. Could kindly share the complete steps. When the two lines you have for df4 I get a different results.

Comment: @ShadowMan Are you getting different results on the data you included in the question?

Comment: Yea I just added your two lines for df4 and the result was not the same.

Comment: Is the first command, `df4 = pd.merge_asof ...`, output different?

Comment: It's the same I pasted your code. I'll double check again when I get back to the desk

Comment: Hey - I have to quit for now.  I would like ot see what you are getting.  You can edit my answer and put in the results for what you are seeing.  I can look at that later or tomorrow.  Be sure to put in the output from both line of code.

Comment: if I set that line equal to a variable then I get the same result as you. i.e.  df5 = df4.assign(.... then df5 is the correct output. Now I would like to update the 'VAL' of df1 based on the calculated 'VAL' in df5)

Comment: I am still very much stuck. You solution correctly gets me the values I need in a new DF. I want to go back to the original DF and substitute those 'VALS' in and leave the other rows alone. I tried the solution on some real data and also was getting some issues. Need a good way to do this that is accurate and consistent. Going to explore other options tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

jch solution works to setup a new df with the Names and Vals required to update df1.

as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d1 = [ ['wp1',0.0,0.0,10],['wp2',10.0,10.0,5],['wp3',7.0,7.0,5]]
d2 = [ ['wp4',0.1,0.1,5],['wp5',10.2,10.2,8]]
headers = ['Name','X','Y','VAL']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1,columns = headers)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2,columns = headers)
df4 = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values(['X','Y']), df2.sort_values(['X','Y']), on='X', direction='nearest', tolerance=1)
print(df4.head())

df5 = df4.assign(VAL=np.where((df4['Y_x']-df4['Y_y']).abs()<1, df4['VAL_x']+df4['VAL_y'], np.nan)).rename(columns={'Name_x':'Name','Y_x':'Y'}).dropna()[['Name','X','Y','VAL']] 
print(df5.head())
print('df1')
print(df1.head())
```

Now I am trying (unsuccsessfully) to update the original df1 and keep the original values where there is not a match.

```
d = df5.set_index('Name')['VAL'].to_dict()
v = df5.filter(like='VAL')
df1[v.columns] = v.replace(d)
print(df1.head())
```

##Edit I now know that this mapping scheme is not a good approach, the values below arent correctly correspondign to the original df.

```
  Name     X     Y   VAL
0  wp1   0.0   0.0  15.0
1  wp2  10.0  10.0   NaN
2  wp3   7.0   7.0  13.0
```

I'd like df1 to be updated like this but insted of NaN for wp2 , it should just show the original VAL of wp2 in df1.

```
df5 = df5.set_index(['Name'])
df1 = df1.set_index(['Name'])

df1.update(df5)
print('df1')
print(df1.head())
```

^ works fine as long as i can use 'Name' as an index for each.

Comment: Perhaps the best way to solve this is to provide and index with the data that has the near matches on x and y and then just merge on that ?